# Is there a way to generate a Microsoft Serialized Certificate Store without Windows?

Tags: powershell, certificate, pkcs#12, smime

Our company uses exclusively Apple devices. At the same time we use Microsoft 365. Using S/MIME on the desktop works but using S/MIME with Outlook for iPhone leads to Outlook for iPhone complaining about the certs not being valid. Earlier certs were rejected with the error message "unable to build chain" (or similar). It hints to Outlook for iPhone not being able to build the chain of trust because of missing root and intermediate CA certs.

I tried importing those as PEM or DER without success. I built the trust chain by concatenating the certs and converting all together into P12/PFX but to no avail.

Reading encrypted mails does work by the way, sending does not.

Microsoft's support now suggests to export the trust chain as Microsoft Serialized Certificate Store (SST extension) but that requires a MMC with certs snap-in. For my own cert I could do that by using a VM but we have more employees than just me. I found several hints at using PowerShell for that but all guides online only explain how to do that using the MMC.

Comment: 1) Did you try to export them in PKCS#7 format? 2) You're specifically asking for Microsoft Serialized Certificate Store -  is it an option for you to use Apple Configurator to create a profile containing the certificates for your Apple devices?

Comment: What exactly does "to no avail" mean? Any error message? Have you not only imported but also trusted the root certificate?

Comment: Trying to import the intermediate cert from GlobalSign in DER: "File could not be loaded" (but in German because my iPhone speaks German with me).

Trying to import the intermediate cert from GlobalSign in PEM: White screen.

The concatenated chain as p12 provoked another message I cannot remember anymore but I'll try to reproduce it on Monday.

Comment: 1) No, I didn't. I'll read into the docs and will try.
2) Can the Apple Configurator provide certificate stores for installed apps? The whole problem stems from Outlok not being able to access the system certificate store. I'm neither into iOS development nor into the Apple Configurator but I'm willing to read documentations.